# How to conditionally render inside a datatable in lightning?

Tags: lightning, conditional, rendering

I have a lightning datatable and into one column called 'Set Primary Contact' I want to display an icon if the custom field IsPrimaryContact__c has the value TRUE, or a button 'Set primary contact' if the field has the value FALSE.

I managed to display only the button and to disabled it if the IsPrimaryContact__c is TRUE.

[image]

Below is the code for this column setting...

```
 {type: "button", label: 'Set Primary Contact', typeAttributes: {
                    label: 'Set Primary Contact',
                    variant: 'brand',
                    name: 'Set Primary Contact',
                    title: 'Set this contact as Primary Contact',
                    disabled: { fieldName: 'IsPrimaryContact__c'},
                    value: 'Set Primary Contact',
                    iconPosition: 'left',
                    onclick: ''
                }}
```

Thank you!

Later Edit: This is an Aura component

Comment: Hi Damira, please let us know if this is a Lightning Web Component or an Aura component.

Comment: Hi, this is an Aura component. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is something like:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!contact.IsPrimaryContact__c}">
        <lightning:icon iconName="action:approval" alternativeText="IsPrimary" />
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <your-button-component-here>
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
</aura:iteration>
```

For more information on how Aura:If works, please refer to the Salesforce docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:if/documentation).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I am not able to use aura:if, as I am setting the columns from the controller.

Comment: I see. I haven't used Aura for a while, but if it's like LWCs you could set some custom js-controller-side property on the contact, like:
` contact.IsPrimaryContact = true ` in the js controller, and
`  <aura:if isTrue="{!contact.IsPrimaryContact}"> ` in the component